# The limitations of Elastic-net regularization

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, elastic-net

I know that Elastic-net regularization is the combination of L1 and L2 regularization.

My question is what are the limitations of Elastic-net regularization?

My question is not related to Elastic-net regularization compared to LASSO or Ridge. Just, I would like to know the possible flaws of Elastic-net regularization.